# Get the url of a redirect with Rest Assured?

Tags: java, redirect, http-redirect, rest-assured, http-status-code-307

I am making a GET request which then makes a 307 redirect to another URL and from there it makes another 302 redirect and so on till it gets to the requested page. I am having problems extracting the URL from the first redirect, the 307, I want to see the location where is redirected to. I am using Rest Assured as framework. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same problem, but I didn't have the 307, just 302. I imagine the solution would be the same. What I did was:

1. stop following the redirects on the first call with `redirects().follow(false)`
2. capture the URL from the first redirect
3. make another call to follow the redirect(s)

   ```
   Response resp1 =
           given().
               contentType(ContentType.URLENC).
               body("AUTH_TOKEN=&j_username=" + encodedUsername + "&j_password=" + password + "&userName=&AUTH_TOKEN=").
               redirects().follow(false).
           expect().
               statusCode(302).
           when().
               post("/authenticate/j_spring_security_check");

   String headerLocationValue = resp1.getHeader("Location");

   Response resp2 =
           given().
               cookie(resp1.getDetailedCookie("JSESSIONID")).
           expect().
               statusCode(200).
           when().
               get(headerLocationValue);
   ```

Comment: Sorry, but in my case, it is not working. I get 200 but I dont get back the json response. I get an empty response string. In fiddler/postman, I correctly get the json response. but not in rest assured.