# POST Call in RestAssured gives 302

Tags: rest-assured, rest

I am performing a POST call in Rest Assured, after a GET (with Basic Authorization, which is pre-req for all my web service calls).
This POST call yields a 302 instead of 201.

Note: I have tried the solution mentioned below, but to no avail:
[get-the-url-of-a-redirect-with-rest-assured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049079/get-the-url-of-a-redirect-with-rest-assured)

Comment: Read through this link - http://biercoff.com/why-rest-assured-doesnt-redirect-post-requests/

Comment: Hi @WilfredClement, thanks for the link. I had checked it out earlier, but I could not find some methods like mergeCookies, parseParamsFromUrl, addCookies (in repsonse), ACCPET in addHeaders.. all these throw error in eclipse. I am on rest assured 4.4.0.

Comment: Yes, those methods are not shown in the above page.